# Ignore formatting changes when comparing .cs files

Tags: visual-studio, diff, git-diff, visual-studio-2019

We work with Visual Studio 2019 in combination with GIT for checking for differences. Our code base primarily makes use of the C# language.

When working on a large feature request we add new code to our existing code base.
When we started building our business-logic and other code we forgot to clean up the code (no formatting and no removal of unnecessary usings). Currently we are making alterations to the existing code base, adding new code, formatting it and cleaning up the dependencies. We do this on different branches.

When we create a merge request for peer review we notice that a lot of the changes to the code-base are changes in formatting. This diverts our attention of validating the code to checking if the code-block has formatting changes.
The whole context switching takes up a lot of energy.

An example of these formatting changes are shown as below.

[image: Minimal example]

In the picture above we see that between the variable file and the equals sign there were two spaces and in the diff the format changes to a single space.

Is there some rule set in Visual Studio 2019 that can altered to disable the checking of certain formatting changes?

If not, any new leads to a solution would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore white space when comparing source in Visual Studio / TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259405/how-to-ignore-white-space-when-comparing-source-in-visual-studio-tfs)